# Passing message client and server using Named Pipes in C#

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I am trying to create an application that uses named pipes to pass data from one application to another. On the first run, The messages are send and received by the server and client respectively. But as soon as that is done, I cannot receive any messages on both the server and client alike.

Here is my code:

**Server Side**

```
public void ServerThread(object data)
        {
            var pipeServer =
                new NamedPipeServerStream(_pipelineName, PipeDirection.InOut, numThreads);

            int threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

            // Wait for a client to connect
            pipeServer.WaitForConnection();

            Console.WriteLine("Client connected on thread[{0}].", threadId);
            try
            {
                // Read the request from the client. Once the client has
                // written to the pipe its security token will be available.
                var ss = new StreamString(pipeServer);

                // Verify our identity to the connected client using a
                // string that the client anticipates.
                ss.WriteString(_securityToken);
                //string filename = ss.ReadString();
                var message = ss.ReadString();

                Console.WriteLine($@"Message received: {message}");
                ss.WriteString("You are connected to the server.");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter message for client.");
                var messageToSend = Console.ReadLine();
                ss.WriteString(messageToSend);
            }
            // Catch the IOException that is raised if the pipe is broken
            // or disconnected.
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            pipeServer.Close();
        }
```

**Client Side**

```
private static string _pipelineName;
        private static string _securityToken;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _pipelineName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PipelineName"];
            _securityToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecurityToken"];

            var pipeClient =
                new NamedPipeClientStream(".", _pipelineName,
                    PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.None,
                    TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation);

            Console.WriteLine($@"Connecting to the server on pipeline {_pipelineName} with password {_securityToken}");
            pipeClient.Connect();

            var ss = new StreamString(pipeClient);
            // Validate the server's signature string.
            if (ss.ReadString() == _securityToken)
            {
                // The client security token is sent with the first write.
                // Send the name of the file whose contents are returned
                // by the server.
                ss.WriteString(@"Client has connected");

                // Print the message to the console.
                Console.Write(ss.ReadString());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server could not be verified.");
            }
            pipeClient.Close();
        }
```

**Sever Engine**

```
public class ServerEngine : IServerEngine
    {
        private static int numThreads = 4;
        private readonly string _pipelineName;
        private readonly string _securityToken;


        public ServerEngine(string pipelineName, string securityToken)
        {
            _pipelineName = pipelineName;
            _securityToken = securityToken;

            Console.WriteLine(
                $@"Server is running on {_pipelineName} with password {securityToken}. {'\n'} Waiting for client to connect...");
        }

        public void ServerThread(object data)
        {
            var pipeServer =
                new NamedPipeServerStream(_pipelineName, PipeDirection.InOut, numThreads);

            int threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

            // Wait for a client to connect
            pipeServer.WaitForConnection();

            Console.WriteLine("Client connected on thread[{0}].", threadId);
            try
            {
                // Read the request from the client. Once the client has
                // written to the pipe its security token will be available.
                var ss = new StreamString(pipeServer);

                // Verify our identity to the connected client using a
                // string that the client anticipates.
                ss.WriteString(_securityToken);
                var message = ss.ReadString();

                Console.WriteLine($@"Message received: {message}");
                ss.WriteString("You are connected to the server.");

                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter message for client");
                    var input = Console.ReadLine();
                    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) break;
                    ss.WriteString(input);
                }
               
            }
            // Catch the IOException that is raised if the pipe is broken
            // or disconnected.
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            pipeServer.Close();
        }

        private void asdfasf()
        {

        }
    }
```

**StreamString**

```
public class StreamString : IStreamString
    {
        private readonly Stream _ioStream;
        private readonly UnicodeEncoding _streamEncoding;

        public StreamString(Stream ioStream)
        {
            _ioStream = ioStream;
            _streamEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        }

        public string ReadString()
        {
            var len = _ioStream.ReadByte() * 256;
            len += _ioStream.ReadByte();
            byte[] inBuffer = new byte[len];
            _ioStream.Read(inBuffer, 0, len);

            return _streamEncoding.GetString(inBuffer);
        }

        public int WriteString(string outString)
        {
            byte[] outBuffer = _streamEncoding.GetBytes(outString);
            int len = outBuffer.Length;
            if (len > UInt16.MaxValue)
            {
                len = ushort.MaxValue;
            }
            _ioStream.WriteByte((byte)(len / 256));
            _ioStream.WriteByte((byte)(len & 255));
            _ioStream.Write(outBuffer, 0, len);
            _ioStream.Flush();

            return outBuffer.Length + 2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems likely that the important/relevant parts are in `StreamString` which we don't have any knowledge of.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, sorry about that Sir. Please see my edit. Thank you.